# How does the MSBuild CoreCompile Target Identify Reference Assemblies

Tags: msbuild, biztalk, biztalk-2009, csc

Can anyone shed any light on how the CoreCompile task in TFS2010 (RC) Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build targets generates the assembly references that are passed to csc.exe?

We are seeing references to both version 2.0 and 4.0 of System.Xml.dll (shown in bold below), however we are using the 'Specific Version: true' flag on the project assembly reference *and* there are no references to the 4.0 assembly in the btproj file:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Csc.exe /noconfig /nowarn:1701,1702 /platform:x86 /errorreport:prompt /warn:4 /define:TRACE 
/reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Configuration.dll 
/reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.dll 
**/reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Xml.dll** 
/reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.dll 
**/reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Xml.dll** 
/reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Data.dll 
/reference:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\System.Web.Services.dll
```

**Update**: I've checked the output of the *ResolveAssemblyReferences* target (from *Microsoft.Common.targets*) and can see that only the assemblies referenced in the project (i.e. the 2.0 framework assemblies) are included in the item list *'_ResolveAssemblyReferenceResolvedFiles'*:

```
ResolveAssemblyReferenceResolvedFiles:
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Configuration.dll;
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.dll;
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Xml.dll
```

However, the CoreCompile target still includes the 4.0 assemblies as detailed above.

**Update 2**: Ok, I've tracked this down to an obscure bug in the *AddBizTalkHiddenReferences* target in the BizTalk build scripts. This particular target attempts to add additional assemblies, including the ones that are duplicated above.

*However*, it uses the GetCORSystemDirectory from 'mscoree.dll' which returns the installation directory of the common language runtime (CLR) that is loaded into the process, in this case the 4.0 framework loaded into MSBuild; as a result, the helper doesn't think it has the System.Xml assembly referenced and adds it, hence the duplicate.

Comment: What is the behavior if you do not set Specific version to true for System.Xml.dll?

Comment: It *doesn't* appear to make any difference.

Comment: Something that I don't understand : do you reference System.Data.dll v4 and System.Web.Services.dll v4?

Comment: madgnome: No, I don't; in fact, I've tracked it down to an obscure bug in the BizTalk 'AddBizTalkHiddenReferences' target. See my update above. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Well done! That's a sneaky one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reference assemblies are resolved by `ResolveAssemblyReferences` target in the file `Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\$(Version)\Microsoft.Common.targets` based on the `Reference` items defined in your project file.